# Fixing method algorithm for finding an age from two dates

Tags: java, algorithm, date, methods, calendar

I dont know how to get my code to work. Right now im getting

> error: no suitable constructor found for GregorianCalendar(SimpleDate)

How do i fix this problem and get my getAge method to calculate a persons age from two dates? Here the code.

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;    

public class UtilsFL {


    public static int readInt(String prompt,boolean guiFlag) {

        if (guiFlag==false){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int data;


        System.out.print(prompt);
        data = input.nextInt();

        return data;
        }
        else if (guiFlag==true) {
        int data;
        data = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt));
        }
        return 0;

      }      




    public static SimpleDate today() {


        Calendar todayCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDate todayDate = new SimpleDate();


        todayDate.setDate(todayCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,  
                          todayCal.get(Calendar.DATE),
                          todayCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        return todayDate;
    }



    public static int getAge(SimpleDate dateBd) {
        int age;
        SimpleDate dateToday = today();


        age = getAge(dateBd, dateToday);  
        return age;

    } 




    public static int getAge(SimpleDate dateBd, SimpleDate dateRef) {
      Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar (dateBd);
      Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
        int rAge = now.get(Calendar.YEAR) - cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     if((cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) > now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
       || (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
       && cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))))
     {
        res--;
     }

        return -1;


    } 

}
```

And here is the code for my SimpleDate class.

```
import java.io.Serializable;        // for object I/O to file

//public class SimpleDate
public class SimpleDate implements Serializable

{
  private int month;
  private int day;
  private int year;

  /** default constructor
  *  sets month to 1, day to 1 and year to 2000
  */
  public SimpleDate( )
  {
    setDate( 1, 1, 2000 );
  }

  /** overloaded constructor
  *  @param mm    initial value for month
  *  @param dd    initial value for day
  *  @param yyyy  initial value for year
  *
  *  passes parameters to set methods
  */
  public SimpleDate( int mm, int dd, int yyyy )
  {
    setMonth( mm );
    setYear( yyyy );
    setDay( dd );
  }

  /* accessor methods */
  int getMonth( ) { return month; }
  int getDay( )   { return day; }
  int getYear( )  { return year; }

  /** mutator method */
  /** setMonth
  *  @param mm new value for month
  *  if mm is between 1 and 12, sets month to mm
  *  otherwise, sets month to 1
  */
  public void setMonth( int mm )
  {
    month = ( mm >= 1 && mm <= 12 ? mm : 1 );
  }

  /** setDay
  *  @param dd new value for day
  *  if dd is legal day for current month, sets day to dd
  *  otherwise, sets day to 1
  */
  public void setDay( int dd )
  {
    day = ( dd >= 1 && isValidDay( dd ) ? dd : 1 );
  }

  /** setYear
  *  @param yyyy new value for year
  *  sets year to yyyy
  */
  public void setYear( int yyyy )
  {
    year = yyyy;
  }

  /** sets date to the next day
  */
  public void nextDay( )
  {
     if ( ! isValidDay( ++day ) )
     {
         day = 1;
         if ( ++month > 12 )
         {
             month = 1;
             year++;
         }
     }
  }

  private boolean isValidDay( int newDay )
  {
     int [] daysInMonth = { 0, 31, 28, 31,
                                30, 31, 30,
                                31, 31, 30,
                               31, 30, 31 };

    if ( newDay > daysInMonth[month] )
    {
       if ( month == 2 && isLeapYear( ) && newDay == 29 )
          return true;
       else
          return false;
    }
    else
       return true;

  }

  private boolean isLeapYear( )
  {
     return !( year % 4 != 0
               ||( year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0 ) );
  }


  /** setDate
  *  @param mm    new value for month
  *  @param dd    new value for day
  *  @param yyyy  new value for year
  *  passes parameters to setMonth, setDay, and setYear
  */
  public void setDate( int mm, int dd, int yyyy )
  {
    setYear( yyyy );  // set year first (could be leap year)
    setMonth( mm );   // set month next
    setDay( dd );     // set day
  }

  /** toString
  *  @return String
  *  returns date in mm/dd/yyyy format
  */
  public String toString( )
  {
    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
  }

  /** equals
  *  @param   d  Object to compare to this object
  *  @return  true if d is equal to this object
  *           false, otherwise
  */
  public boolean equals( Object d )
  {
    if ( !( d instanceof SimpleDate ) )
       return false;
    SimpleDate d1 = (SimpleDate)d;
    if ( month == d1.month
         && day == d1.day
         && year == d1.year )
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: why would you image that a JDK method would have a constructor for your custom class `Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar (dateBd);` ?

Comment: Instead of using antiquated methods for calculating the difference between two dates, use Java 8's Timer API or JodaTime which provides this support out of the box - More accurately then simply trying to calculate the difference between the milliseconds of two times

Comment: @ScaryWombat because im a little bit retarded..thanks

Answer (score -1):

Do this to get their birth in only years:

```
public static int getAge(SimpleDate dateBd, SimpleDate dateRef) {
          return dateRef.getYear() - dateBd.getYear();
    }
```

You can also do this to get their full age in milliseconds and then do what you want with it:

```
public static long getAge(SimpleDate dateBd, SimpleDate dateRef) {
         Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         c.set(dateBd.getYear(), dateBd.getMonth(), dateBd.getDay()); //Note: 0 is for January
         long birth = c.getTimeInMillis();
         c.set(dateRef.getYear(), dateRef.getMonth(), dateRef.getDay());
         long ref = c.getTimeInMillis();
         return ref - birth;
    }
```

Edit: Also you should consider using java's built in libraries such as Date: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html